# How to create an Azure VM from an existing managed disk with PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-managed-disk

What I've tried at first:

```
# fetch existing disk and network interface
$disk = Get-AzDisk -DiskName "MyDiskName" -ResourceGroupName "MyRgName"
$ni = Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name "MiNiName" -ResourceGroupName "MyRgName"

# create vm configuration
$vmConfig = New-AzVMConfig -VMName "MyVmName" -VMSize "Standard_D2_v5" -SecurityType "TrustedLaunch" | `
Set-AzVMBootDiagnostic -Enable -ResourceGroupName "MyRgName" | `
Set-AzVMOSDisk -CreateOption "Attach" -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id | `
Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -Id $ni.Id.

# create vm
New-AzVM -VM $vmConfig -ResourceGroupName "MyRgName" -Location "Australia East"
```

However, the New-AzVM command fails with this:

> Required parameter 'osDisk.osType' is missing (null).
> ErrorCode: InvalidParameter
> ErrorMessage: Required parameter 'osDisk.osType' is
> missing (null).
> ErrorTarget: osDisk.osType
> StatusCode: 400
> ReasonPhrase:
> OperationID : d5e4e899-6c4e-42e8-94fd-47f0350ab7a5

Then, if I try adding the OS flag to the Set-AzVMOSDisk as follows...

```
Set-AzVMOSDisk -Windows -CreateOption "Attach" -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id
```

I get the following error:

> Set-AzVMOSDisk:
> Line 3
> Set-AzVMOSDisk -Windows -CreateOption "Attach" -ManagedDiskId $disk.I …
> Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or
> an insufficient number of parameters were provided.

That flag does seem unnecessary, since I am not trying to create a VM off an empty disk, and the existing disk already has that information in it:

```
"name": "MyDiskName",
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/disks",
"location": "australiaeast",
"sku": {
   "name": "StandardSSD_LRS",
   "tier": "Standard"
},
"properties": {
   "osType": "Windows",
   "hyperVGeneration": "V2",
   "supportedCapabilities": {
      "diskControllerTypes": "SCSI",
      "acceleratedNetwork": true,
      "architecture": "x64"
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to create an Azure VM from an existing managed disk with PowerShell?

Here is the updated `PowerShell` script to create **Azure VM** from an existing **managed disk**.

```
$VMName ="venkatdemo"
$azureVmSize = "Standard_D2_v5"
$Rgname = "rg-name"
    
$disk = Get-AzDisk -DiskName "venkat-vm-os-disk" -ResourceGroupName $Rgname
$ni = Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name "VM_Nic" -ResourceGroupName $Rgname
$VirtualMachine = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $azureVmSize -SecurityType "Standard"
$VirtualMachine = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $ni.Id 
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -StorageAccountType "Standard_LRS" -Name $disk.Name -CreateOption Attach -Windows -DeleteOption Delete -Verbose
New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $Rgname  -Location "westus2" -VM $VirtualMachine -Verbose
```

**Output:**

[image]